# What is the limitation with one-node Cassandra cluster?

Tags: java, docker, cassandra, opscenter, nosql

I am experimenting with Cassandra and Opscenter.  In the Opscenterd's log file, I found this line

> 2015-07-29 16:10:16+0000 [] ERROR: Problem while calling CreateClusterConfController (SingleNodeProvisioningError): Due to a limitation with one-node clusters, OpsCenter will not be able to communicate with the Datastax Agent unless list
>   en_address/broadcast_address in cassandra.yaml are set to 172.17.42.1. Please ensure these match before continuing.

Because I deployed Cassandra and Opscenter in different Docker containers, I must set `listen_address` to the container's internal IP (because Cassandra sitting in a container knows nothing about its host) and `broadcast_address` to the corresponding host's bridge IP.  This is the normal setup if you deploy Cassandra on machines behind separate gateways (like AWS EC2 where each instance has a private and a public IP).

**Question 1**: What exactly is the limitation with one-node cluster?

**Question 2**: How should I workaround the problem in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a Opscenter limitation?  Because Cassandra used to have only one address (listen and broadcast were the same).  Is Opscenter not adapted to the latest Cassandra yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1: What exactly is the limitation with one-node cluster?

OpsCenter (via underlying python driver) is reading cluster information from Cassandra’s `system` tables (namely, `system.peers` and `system.local`), with most of the information coming from `system.peers`, including broadcast interfaces for each of the nodes.

However, that table does not contain information about the node itself, only about its peers. When there are no peers, there is no way to get broadcast address from Cassandra itself, and that’s what OpsCenter uses to tie actual Cassandra instances to the internal representation. In this case OpsCenter uses whatever address you specified as a seed (`172.17.42.1` here), and when agents report with a different IP (they’re getting Cassandra’s broadcast address via JMX), OpsCenter would discard those messages.

> Question 2: How should I workaround the problem in this case?

Try setting `local_address` in `address.yaml` to `172.17.42.1`, this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks arre, setting `local_address` in `address.yaml` did the trick.